# Ctrl-o in vimpulse?

Tags: emacs, viper, viper-mode, vimpulse

does anyone know how to enable `Ctrl-o` to switch to normal-mode for one command in `viper-mode` or `vimpulse`? In viper-mode it's bound to open-line (which is what it does for vanilla Emacs and in vimpulse it is bound to `(vimpulse-jump-backward ARG)`. I'm using Viper-mode + vimpulse at level 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in insert-mode and want to execute one Vimpulse command :

```
(vimpulse-imap "\C-o" 'viper-escape-to-vi)
```

(it is bound by default to C-z in insert-mode)

Comment: shoot, I'd basically given up vimpulse/viper months ago when I couldn't find this...

Comment: This only escapes to vi for a single command. That is, it says "Switched to VI state for the next command..." and indeed after you do a single command it drops you back into insert mode.  Is there a better option?

Comment: @Frew : I don't get you, Frew. Better option for? The OP only wanted to escape to VI state for a single command. I imagine you would just switch to the real VI state for longer edits :) btw, I map M-h (Meta-h or Alt-h) to viper-intercept-ESC-key so that it's as easy as possible to get back to Normal mode. `(global-set-key (kbd "M-h") 'viper-intercept-ESC-key)`