# Invoke single normal-mode command with Ctrl-o in Vimpulse?

Tags: emacs, viper-mode, vimpulse

The usual behavior in vim is for `C-o` in insert-mode to allow the user to use one normal-mode command and then return to insert-mode.

Following the suggestions in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708533/ctrl-o-in-vimpulse), I've set

```
(vimpulse-imap "\C-o" 'viper-escape-to-vi)
```

But when I press `C-o` in insert-mode, the characters "^O" are inserted in the buffer and I am unable to switch to normal-mode for one command as I expect. I understand `viper-escape-to-vi` is bound to `C-z` by default but I am also unable to switch to normal-mode using this key combination either ("^Z" is printed in the buffer instead). What am I doing wrong?

Also, second question: I would like for `C-z` to not be bound by viper-mode (or vimpulse) as I use it for elscreen. How can I tell it to leave `C-z` alone?

**Edit:** Found this bit of code in vimpulse-misc-keybindings.el:

```
;; temporarily escape to vi state
(define-key viper-insert-basic-map "\C-o" 'viper-escape-to-vi)
```

So should be defined already? Not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1) It works for me, maybe something went wrong with your config?

But the output is strange: The only way to get it is a quoted-insert (or similar).

`viper-escape-to-vi` in insert state is bound to `viper-toggle-key` (but well that defaults to C-z), so see below. Again your output is strange.

Ad 2) You have to set `viper-toggle-key` to a sexp *before* viper is loaded, alternatively customize it.

For the former (using the Pause key for it)

```
(setq viper-toggle-key [pause])
(require 'viper)
```

---

You should try [evil](http://gitorious.org/evil/pages/Home), being the successor to vimpulse. It's coming along well and gets rid of viper.

Setting the toggle key there (to pause again) is a `(evil-set-toggle-key "<pause>")` away, it's a kbd sequence not a sexp.
C-o works fine, too.

Comment: Even if I start emacs with `emacs -Q` and then load viper or vimpulse (setting `viper-toggle-key` a priori), I get the same problem. I am using Emacs 24 on OS X that I built from the git repository -- possibly this is the problem. I did not know about evil -- seems not very mature yet but `C-o` works out of the box!

Comment: Yes, that could be a reason, you should ask on the emacs-dev mailinglist for help with this. Evil is not very mature in terms of time but it's fairly stable and feature complete (compared with vimpulse -- except for extensive documentation).